# After updating site to use SSL all images in posts point to http://

Tags: ssl, https

I recently upgrade my site to use SSL through a reverse proxy. I have changed the WordPress address and site address in the Settings menu and the main page loads just fine: https://www.scotthelme.co.uk

If you click through to one of my posts however you get mixed content warnings on the SSL certificate: https://www.scotthelme.co.uk/wifi-pineapple-karma-sslstrip/

I see the images on the page are still pointing to the http:// URL they were added with but I would have thought that my redirect would force them to be served over https://, this doesn't seem to be the case. Either way I'm happy to rewrite them to protocol relative URLs, I'm just not sure on the best way. How is it best to go about changing the URLs for the images in posts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing the [WordPress HTTPS](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/) plugin should take care of it.

Comment: I assume it shouldn't have any adverse affects on the rest of the site? I was wondering if there was just a SQL query or some other method without depending on a plugin.

Comment: I'd also rather see the core adapt this, but as long as it doesn't, the plugin is the best solution. And it is dependable, well written and usually adapted to a new WP quickly after a release.

Comment: It seems to be up and running without a problem, thanks for the tip.

Comment: An alternative plugin that is actively maintained is Really Simple SSL: https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/

Answer (score 0):

After Implementing SSL, any link or image have http then you always get mixed content warnings in Console and page will not work properly,

so you should fix all `http` to => `https` by manually or plugin